# Training a model but on the command line the val_loss is 0.0000e+00 and accuracy is 1.0000

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

Is there something wrong when I get thsese kinds of numbers, knowing that it isn't supposed to be like this? I think I'm parsing to my dataset incorrectly but I don't know if that's the cause of it.

When I try testing with this model, the output results are 100% accurate with the wrong label and every other label is 0%, having four possible labels. Could someone help me on this, I really dont know what to do? Thank You.

I've included the full codes of my training and testing codes. I've also included the exact command i use to train.

Training code

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use("Agg")

from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from keras.opti
mizers import Adam
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from keras.preprocessing.image import img_to_array
from keras.utils import to_categorical
from pyimagesearch.lenet import LeNet
from imutils import paths
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import argparse
import random
import cv2
import os

ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument("-d", "--dataset", required=True,
    help="path to input dataset")
ap.add_argument("-m", "--model", required=True,
    help="path to output model")
ap.add_argument("-p", "--plot", type=str, default="plot.png",
    help="path to output loss/accuracy plot")
args = vars(ap.parse_args())

EPOCHS = 250
#EPOCHS = 5
INIT_LR = 1e-3
BS = 32

print("[INFO] loading images...")
data = []
labels = []

imagePaths = sorted(list(paths.list_images(args["dataset"])))
random.seed(42)
random.shuffle(imagePaths)


for imagePath in imagePaths:

    image = cv2.imread(imagePath)
    image = cv2.resize(image, (28, 28))
    image = img_to_array(image)
    data.append(image)

    label = imagePath.split(os.path.sep)[1]
    if label == "F15":
        label_type = 1
    elif label == "F16":
        label_type = 2
    elif label == "Bird":
        label_type = 3
    else: 
        label_type = 0

    labels.append(label_type)

data = np.array(data, dtype="float") / 255.0
labels = np.array(labels)

(trainX, testX, trainY, testY) = train_test_split(data,
    labels, test_size=0.25, random_state=42)

trainY = to_categorical(trainY, num_classes=4)
testY = to_categorical(testY, num_classes=4)

aug = ImageDataGenerator(rotation_range=30, width_shift_range=0.1,
    height_shift_range=0.1, shear_range=0.2, zoom_range=0.2,
    horizontal_flip=True, fill_mode="nearest")

print("[INFO] compiling model...")
model = LeNet.build(width=28, height=28, depth=3, classes=4)
opt = Adam(lr=INIT_LR, decay=INIT_LR / EPOCHS)
model.compile(loss="categorical_crossentropy", optimizer=opt,
    metrics=["accuracy"])

print("[INFO] training network...")
H = model.fit_generator(aug.flow(trainX, trainY, batch_size=BS),
    validation_data=(testX, testY), steps_per_epoch=len(trainX) // BS,
    epochs=EPOCHS, verbose=1)


print("[INFO] serializing network...")
model.save(args["model"])

plt.style.use("ggplot")
plt.figure()
N = EPOCHS
plt.plot(np.arange(0, N), H.history["loss"], label="train_loss")
plt.plot(np.arange(0, N), H.history["val_loss"], label="val_loss")
plt.plot(np.arange(0, N), H.history["accuracy"], label="train_acc")
plt.plot(np.arange(0, N), H.history["val_accuracy"], label="val_acc")
plt.title("Training Loss and Accuracy on F15/F16/Bird/Airplane")
plt.xlabel("Epoch #")
plt.ylabel("Loss/Accuracy")
plt.legend(loc="lower left")
plt.savefig(args["plot"])
plt.show()
```

Testing code

```
from keras.preprocessing.image import img_to_array
from keras.models import load_model
import numpy as np
import argparse
import imutils
import cv2

ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument("-m", "--model", required=True,
    help="path to trained model model")
ap.add_argument("-i", "--image", required=True,
    help="path to input image")
args = vars(ap.parse_args())

image = cv2.imread(args["image"])
orig = image.copy()

image = cv2.resize(image, (28, 28))
image = image.astype("float") / 255.0
image = img_to_array(image)
image = np.expand_dims(image, axis=0)

print("[INFO] loading network...")
model = load_model(args["model"])

(Airplane, F15,F16, Bird) = model.predict(image)[0] 
print("F15: ", F15)
print("F16: ", F16)
print("Bird: ", Bird)
print("Airplane: ", Airplane)
classes =["F15", "F16", "Bird", "Airplane"]
results = [F15, F16, Bird, Airplane]

i = np.argmax(results)
label = classes[i]
proba = max(results) 

label = "{}: {:.2f}%".format(label, proba * 100)

output = imutils.resize(orig, width=400)
cv2.putText(output,  label, (10, 25),  cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.7, (0, 255, 0), 2)

cv2.imshow("Output", output)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Command Line

```
C:\Users\ggian\Desktop\FYP\image-classification-keras>python train_network.py --dataset image --model trial.model
```

Within the dataset 'image', it contains four other folders, each containing around 400 images

Comment: try to restructure your code in order to be able to check every step of your program. For example, are classes correctly associated with images? Are the labels you fetch correct? Maybe you are setting all labels to 0? Try use functions, each one checking the input correctness and ensuring a correct output. Also, try to use the smallest dataset possible and see if it works. If you set labels randomly does it keep having 0 loss?

Comment: just to confirm a few things, classes correctly associated with images? Does this mean if i have 4 classes, therefore 4 labels, meaning 4 folders with 4 labels?

Comment: I mean ensuring that each image has the correct label associated with it when it's putted into the data+labels objects. Also post your actual program output so we can better see what's happening. Is the model by chance always predicting label 0? Is the loss decrease instant in the first steps or gradual?

Comment: @HitLuca Now it's working, I hadn't parse the correct path and had been using an unupdated code instead of the one in the project folder. Thanks for the help!

Comment: glad you solved it :)